# Any Idea why this page is loading so slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website / cms that I've been working on that loads some CSS and JS Automatically, and I'm trying to find out what's making my site load so slow. I do run SQL queries and such, but I've utilized them plenty in the past and had no issues. I did notice earlier that my server is only uploading at 5 mbs, but I wouldn't see that causing the load times I'm seeing. My Average Page Load Time is 13 Seconds (The average user will give up on a site after 2-3 seconds) I'm attaching a screenshot of my load speeds as well.

`pre.loader`

```
LoadCSS("bootstrap");
LoadCSS("font-awesome");
```

`post.loader`

```
LoadJS("jquery");
LoadJS("bootstrap");
```

`theme.loader`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
DEFINE("LAYOUT", "full_width");
?>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<?php LoadThemeCSS("style.css"); ?>
</head>
<?php DEFINE("D15ROOT", dirname(__file__)); ?>
<?php include_once(dirname(__file__).'/parts/navigation.tpl'); ?>
<?php 

include_once(dirname(__file__).'/layouts/'.LAYOUT.'.tpl');
?>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
  <p class="navbar-text navbar-left">&copy; <?php echo SITE_NAME; ?> <?php echo ESTABLISHED_YEAR; ?> - <?php echo date('Y'); ?></p>
  </div>
</div>
<?php LoadThemeJS("navigation.js"); ?>
```

`LoadThemeJS` and `LoadThemeCSS` Functions are hooks to call a function within my class

```
public function LoadThemeCSS($arg) {
    $path = str_replace(root_p, "//".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], theme_p.'/'.ATHEME.'/css/'.$arg);
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/stylesheet' href='".$path."'>";
}
public function LoadThemeJS($arg) {
    $path = str_replace(root_p, "//".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], theme_p.'/'.ATHEME.'/js/'.$arg);
    echo "<script src='".$path."'></script>";
}
```

And my Class Function to Call The Bootstrap CSS

```
        public function LoadBootStrapCSS() {
            ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->assetpath; ?>/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <?php
        }
```

I'm not sure if any of that helps; it's just my own framework I've been working on. All the functions work and call correctly. What I can't figure out is the high load time.
[image: Load Times of Assets]

Index.php (IE doxramos.tk)

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

require_once(dirname(__file__).'/main.con');
$command = isset($_POST['process']) ? $_POST['process'] : NULL;
    if(!$command) {
        //Load The Assets CSS
        RunLoader("pre");
        RunLoader("plugins");
        RunLoader("theme");
        RunLoader("post");
    }
    else {
        //Load Post Called Functions
    }
```

Comment: Does your server keep a temporary cache. If so clearing that might increase the response time

Comment: Its the index.php file and I'm not sure. I'll look and I'll also throw in the main portion there.

Comment: Well it isn't the downloading or uploading that is your problem

Comment: All the green is your computer waiting for the server to respond

Comment: So it's the time it takes the server to process the connection.

Comment: Can you run it on the server and take the network out of the question?

Comment: I can try. I've heard there's some terminal web browsers out there, but I don't know how well that would work.

Comment: why dont you analyse your page speed from google insights and try those suggestions\,https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/.

Comment: My main idea would be that your server keeps a static cache of the web page to make loading faster but the more out of date that cache is the longer it takes the server to process changes made since the cache was created. So if you refresh the cache it would reduce response time. I had that happen on a godaddy Wordpress site I worked on

Comment: I'll look into that Binvention. I've never dealt with that, so I'll see what I can find on it. I'm restarting the VPS now to see if that can give me some speed increase possibly. Dreamweiver. I actually ran an insight a few hours ago and it wasn't really give me much. A few small suggestions that I'm looking into, but it gave me an 86/100

Comment: @Binvention I'm not really finding anything on apache and static caching. It seems like a good theory though; this is essentially revamped and improved version of what I used to use, so it's logical.

Comment: It is some server side processing that is taking your time so it would be easier to troubleshoot from the server end

Comment: I'm not sure what. Right now I only have it pulling a small amount of sql to load the pages, the plugins are pulled using a config.xml file and running simplexml_load. I did change the extensions just because I wanted to make the CMS more "my own". Would changing extensions from PHP hurt the processing?

Comment: The only way I could see checking from the server side would be to install a gui onto the server and then using VNC to connect. would that impact performance horribly?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is at this point but for the time being I'd recommend a static page that can load first then everything that requires processing loads on top of that so that your users see something come up immediately even though it's not functional for another ten seconds

Comment: I'll look into that, Right now I'm commenting out blocks. It seems like it slows down whenever I enable more JS and CSS